# Find next N rows in MySQL table ordered by a not unique column

Tags: mysql, select

I couldn't find a way to do it and am not sure how to search for this question, as all I've found were not exactly what I wanted and the answers not applicable.

I have a table with two fields (char and num), 'num' is unique but 'char' not, as in the example:

```
char | num
_________
a    | 2
b    | 1
c    | 3
c    | 4 <-- I am here
c    | 7
c    | 8
d    | 5
e    | 9
f    | 6
```

what I want is to fetch N rows beginning in the line marked with the table ordered by 'char'.

I'm using

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE char >= $current_char ORDER BY char,num LIMIT $N
```

but it doesn't do what I want, as it starts from the row with char='c' and num='3'.

EDIT: I will probably count and use xdazz's answer because the code will be clearer, but it looks that I could do this other way:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE char > $current_char OR (char = $current_char AND num >= $current_num) ORDER BY char,num LIMIT $N
```

but it is not very pretty.

Comment: it solved your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You marked `<-- I am here` means you know that is the forth record, so you could just do :

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY char,num LIMIT 4, $N
```

Comment: actually not, I know I am with in the row that have char='c' and num='4' but don't know that I am in the 4th row of the table or the 2nd occurrence of char='c'. But maybe I can count where I am first and then use your query. Thanks, I didn't know that LIMIT could have 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you used `where char >= current_char` , but the chars u said they are not unique , si it can be row 5 or row 6 but instead use the unique rows 
like that

```
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE num >= $current_num ORDER BY char LIMIT $N
```

u cant say char > somechar

Comment: but then if 'b' had a higher id then $current_num it would appear in the result, and I only want things from 'c' and after

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that you haven't described what your selection criteria are.

You have indicated that you want to start at the record marked `<-- I am here`, but you haven't defined what distinguishes that record from any other record.

Once you can define what is special about that record and why you want to start there, someone here will be able to help you write a query to find that record. Otherwise, we're all just guessing.

Comment: I am displaying a list in the screen, but load it by parts because it can be a very large list, and it is dynamic. When I come to the end of the loaded list I need to fetch the next N rows. The way I am currently doing makes me loop forever if the occurrences of rows with char='c' is bigger than N. Don't know if I am very clear now, but the combination of (char,num) is unique and the order of the list is decided by 'char' first and then 'num'.